# Codeigniter Apache to nginx rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I just transferred my website from GoDaddy (Apache) to DigitalOcean (Nginx/LEMP). The Web site was developed using PHP/CodeIgniter. I am only able to see the first page (index.php). It works if I provide the full URL of any file, but I cannot access URL rewrites. Looks like some issue with my .htaccess file...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help or link/tutorial on how to move from Apache to Nginx will be helpful.

Comment: Show your htaccess

Comment: Nginx does not use `.htaccess`, that's an Apache configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

Your whole rewrite rule converted to one line

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

to

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

The update/edit your default nginx file by

```
nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

and restart the service

```
sudo nginx service restart
```

Thanks for thos who looked and replied.